# User log capture

Tags: php, mysql

I want to log the details of editing in database table. The table has multiple fields. May be some fields edits others replace the same values. How can i add  updated details  as a message into log table in php/mysql?

Comment: unclear question, add more detail. show what you had done so far.

Comment: I have two mysql tables. Details table and log table. details table has multiple columns,
When i view the selected row it shows all the existing values from detail table. if i made any changes on any field that message has to be passed into log table, some time same value replacing some time different values , I want to log message only for different values